# Combine multiple row's records in one row with MS Access Query?

Tags: performance, ms-access, ms-access-2007, query-performance

I have a table (name- tbl2) with 21 column but I want to combine multiple rows records in a row by using a unique reference number as below:

**Table Field and Records Type**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query will solve your problem:

```
SELECT ID, STUFF(
     (SELECT ', ' + CAST(Item AS VARCHAR(20)) [text]
     FROM TBL12
     WHERE ID = t.ID
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Items
FROM TBL12 t
GROUP BY ID
```

Since you add many tags in the post, I solved in MSSQL using STUFF. 
Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d805d/4

Answer (score 1):

This is most easily accomplished in an Access query by using the [ConcatRelated()](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function. For more information see the following question on Stack Overflow:

[Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13278590/2144390)